# Array return undefined => values will not get pushed

Tags: javascript

```
function calculate(n1, n2, o) {
var num1 = (n1).toString(); 
var num2 = (n2).toString(); 
getNumber(num1);
getNumber(num2);
var valueArray = [x];
var number1;
var number2;
var counter2;
var newArray = [];
function getNumber(number){
    var addition = 0;
    var counter = num1.length - 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < num1.length; i++){
     if(number[i] != "0"){
        addition += Math.pow(2, counter);
     }
    counter --;
    }
    newArray.push(addition);
}

}
calculate(1101, 1101);
```

I am trying to push the value of addition to newArray and am recieving an error saying "cannot read property push of undefined." Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most. While i'm here, you left an answer over here that was correct, i'd suggest undeleting it. :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/33445671/400654

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `getNumber(num1);` before you initialise the array. Move the line `var newArray = [];` above your calls to getNumber

Answer (score 0):

Basically 'newArray' is not initialized.
If you want to preserve 'newArray' between executions of the function:

```
if(!newArray)
    newArray = new Array();
newArray.push(addition);
```