# Error handling in Express using Axios for API call

Tags: api, express, error-handling, async-await, axios

I am trying to set up a basic express app to get some API data using axios. I want to do things the right way but I am a bit lost with error handling. Ideally, if there is an error I want to communicate it to users which I could do if the API call was within it the route. But how do you do it if it's a separate function?

axios call function using async:

```
const getForm = async () => {
    try {
        const config = {
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://api.something.org/niceform'
            }
        }
        const response = await axios(config)
        return response
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message
    }
}
```

express route:

```
app.get('/niceform', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await getForm()
        res.send(data)
    } catch (error) {
        ???
    }
})
```

If I understand it correctly the `getForm()` function will return either the response or the error and then the route will send whatever comes back. But then what does the route's catch block do and how should I use it?

Is this setup considered to be a good practice? 
Any advice would be appreciated, I am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catch block can be removed from the `getForm` function. An error will be caught anyways in the `get` route.

```
const getForm = async () => {
    const config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://api.something.org/niceform'
    };

    const response = await axios(config);

    return response;
}
```

Or the error can be caught inside `getForm`, in order to do something in that catch block, and be thrown:

```
const getForm = async () => {
    const config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://api.something.org/niceform'
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios(config);
        return response;
    } catch (err) {
        // log the error
        // add extra information to the error
        // else
        // (see the attached answer)
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Consequently, in the catch block in the `get` route, an error can be responded:

```
app.get('/niceform', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await getForm();
        res.send(data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.error(error);
    }
})
```

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42171508/3563737
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much for the explanation, this makes complete sense! :)