# populate my throw object with error message in json response

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to populate my error object `{'status': response.status, 'msg': ''}` with the error message present in the JSON Response of the API if there is any, otherwise throw the error object without any message.
But `throw {'status': response.status, 'msg': ''}` statement is hit before the `json_response` promise is evaluated and everytime i get the empty message.

How can I populate the message attribute in my error object?

```
    return await fetch(url.toString(), {
        method: 'post',
        headers: get_headers(url, request_body),
        body: JSON.stringify(request_body)
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(`API Status: ${response.status} API ${url.toString()}`)

            if (!response.ok) {
                // response.json()
                //     .then(json_response => {
                //         console.log(json_response)
                //         logger.error(json_response)
                //         throw {'status': response.status, 'msg': json_response?.errorMessage?.message}
                //     })
                //     .catch((e)=>{
                //         throw e
                //     })
                throw {'status': response.status, 'msg': ''}
            }

            return response.json()
        })
        .then((json_response) => {
            return json_response

        })
}
```

Comment: You want to get the body of the response before the response body has been received? Why not just throw the error in the `then` where you get the `json_response`. Also, why are you using `then` when you `await` the `fetch`? Just do `const resp = await fetch(...); const parse = await resp.json();` Or remove `await` and return the (unawaited) promise...

Comment: I am using `then(json_response)` block to signal everything went well

Comment: Btw, [drop the pointless `.then(json_response => { return json_response })`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572) as well as [the equally pointless `.catch(e=> { throw e; });`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42167274/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But `throw {'status': response.status, 'msg': ''}` statement is hit before the `json_response` promise is evaluated and everytime i get the empty message.

Well you can't have both at once! Also you'll need to `return` the promise with the error response:

```
.then((response) => {
    console.log(`API Status: ${response.status} API ${url.toString()}`)

    if (!response.ok) {
        return response.json()
//      ^^^^^^
           .then(json_response => {
               console.log(json_response)
               logger.error(json_response)
               throw {'status': response.status, 'msg': json_response?.errorMessage?.message}
           });
    }

    return response.json()
})
```

Btw, when inspecting a http error response, I would recommend to always check the [`Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) before parsing it as JSON. Many error responses are still html pages or plain text, even for JSON APIs.