# differences between return Promise.reject , and, throw new Error

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm studying the differences between   return Promise.reject , and, throw new Error, looks similar , here the catch code:

```
} catch (err) {
  return Promise.reject(err);
  //throw new Error(err);
}
```

for throw new Error I see only is added 'TypeError'

sometimes i use, inside async function, and looks works all fine too..

```
throw(err);

    {
        "data": {
            "userlogs": null
        },
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined",
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "line": 2,
                        "column": 3
                    }
                ],
                "path": [
                    "userlogs"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

with Promise the message is cleaner:

```
    {
        "data": {
            "userlogs": null
        },
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined",
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "line": 2,
                        "column": 3
                    }
                ],
                "path": [
                    "userlogs"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

is there and advise about that? i'm using await for call the functions, it's better to use Promise.reject in that scenary,  and throw new Error is used for any case?

Comment: The important difference is that the `throw` constructs a new `Error` instance, while the `Promise` version does not. I suspect that if you returned `Promise.reject(new Error(err));` or changed the `throw` to just `throw err;` then the behaviors would be identical.

Comment: See this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw] may help you

Comment: thanks four your responses...I've changed everything to Promise.reject