# How to send value from Promise 'then' to 'catch'?

Tags: javascript, json, promise, ipc

I just want to ask how should I pass the resolve promise to `catch` if the value on the resolve is not intended.

e.g.

```
let prom = getPromise();

prom.then(value => {
    if (value.notIWant) {
        // Send to catch <-- my question is here, I want to pass it on the catch.
    }

    // Process data.
}).catch(err => {
    // Pass the error through ipc using json, for logging.
});
```

I tried to using `throw` but the object cant be parsed to json and just got an empty object.

**ANSWER:**

@BohdanKhodakivskyi first comment below is the answer I want.

@31py answer is also correct but the @BohdanKhodakivskyi solution is much simplier and will render the same result.

Comment: Have you tried `throw value;` ?

Comment: Also check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw

Comment: @BohdanKhodakivskyi thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: Glad it did the job. I added it to the answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `throw value;`. In your case:

```
prom.then(value => {
    if (value.notIWant) {
        // Send to catch
        throw value;
    }

    // Process data.
}).catch(err => {
    // Pass the error through ipc using json, for logging.
});
```

Please also note the difference and limitations between using `Promise.reject()` and `throw` which is perfectly described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw). For example, `throw` will not work in some `async` scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, actually as long as possible I can omit using callback, I wont use it.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply return a rejected promise:

```
prom.then(value => {
    if (value.notIWant) {
        return Promise.reject('your custom error or object');
    }

    // Process data.
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err); // prints 'your custom error or object'
});
```

`.catch` actually handles any promise rejection in the chain, so if you're returning a rejected promise, the control automatically flows to `catch`.

Comment: Thanks, it works but @BohdanKhodakivskyi comment is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

why you just not rethrow the error? `throw new Error("something");`

Comment: Doing this the ```JSON.stringify``` will result an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use outside `functions` to do it:

```
var processData = function(data) {
   // process data here
}

var logIt = function(data) {
   // do logging here..
}

let prom = getPromise();

prom.then(value => {
    if (value.notIWant) {
        // Send to catch <-- my question is here, I want to pass it on the catch.
        logIt(/*pass any thing*/);
    }

    // Process data.
    processData(data);

}).catch(err => {
      logIt(/*pass any thing*/);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, actually this is what I am doing, but I am trying not to do things twice. I mean writing the ```logIt``` twice.

Comment: you gonna write something some where twice, it's either `reject`, or this method `logIt`

Comment: Actually this is what DRY is about, you move the code to shared method and call it many times in different places.

Comment: Yup, I understand you, and I also use that, but there is some scenario that the ```logIt``` cant handle, and need some processing for special cases before it will passed to  ```logIt``` method, so I don't want to write does special process in two blocks or create a new method just for that.