# Does using Promise and not rejecting it cause memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, es6-promise

The code goes like this:

```
function test(value){
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
     try {
       fulfill(true);
     } catch(e) {
       throw e;
     }
  });
}
```

My concern is, when you use `Promise` and `throw error` instead of `reject(e)`, will this cause a memory leak?

Because for me, throwing an error instead of rejecting it will not reject or exit the error outside promise. The error will just go around inside the `Promise`. Let me know your opinion.

Comment: How is this a duplicate if this one is about ES/JS native `Promise`s and the other one is for jQuery `Promise`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throwing an error will automatically reject the `Promise`. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw)

But there is something to discuss about. Look at the following code. The code throw an error.the error is thrown from the inside of a promise. It will automatically rejected and initiate the catch chain.

```
function test(value){
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){

       throw e;

  });
}

test('sample text').then(result=>console.log(result)).catch(result=>console.log(result))
```

But what if I've used a Web API e.g `setTimeout()` inside my promise. Look at the following code:

```
function test(value){
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
       setTimeout(function(){
          throw new Error('haha');
       },1000)


  });
}

test('sample text').then(result=>console.log(result)).catch(result=>console.log(result))
```

Web APIs are asynchronous. Whenever a Web API is called from inside a promise, the JavaScript engine take that `async` code outside for execution. In simpler words, web APIs or asynchronous code gets executed outside of the main call stack.

So, throwing an error from `setTimeout()` won't have any reference of the caller promise, thus can't initiate the `catch` block. You need to `reject()` it from `setTimeout()` to initiate the `catch` block if there is any error.

***Will it cause a memory leak?***

***Answer:*** **`no`**

the **`test().then().catch()`** will be garbage collected as soon as it finished executing. But if you would've kept the promise in a global variable like **`var p = test(); p.then().catch()`** then the variable **`p`** will stay in memory, it won't be garbage collected. But that's not a memory leak. Memory leak is a completely different aspect and doesn't apply in this kind of scenario.

Comment: It will, but it's also irrelevant for a memory leak.  A promise is just a Javascript object and will be garbage collected when nobody retains a reference to it, whether it's resolved, rejected or still pending.

Comment: @jfriend00 - it will cause memory leak if there are lots of pending and rejected processes that needs to be garbage collected right? So if those processes are bumping up, those will create leaks since it consumes memory. Correct?

Comment: @happygolucky - No.  An object that will be garbage collected is not a leak.  A leak is something that will never be garbage collected.  Leaks by definition are something that accumulate and are not cleaned up by the system.  If you're in a tight loop making millions of objects that need to be garbage collected that might create a temporary memory problem, but that's not a leak or an issue caused by what this question is about.

Answer (score 1):

This will not cause a memory leak. However, there are differences worth to consider when using one or the other.

- Unlike `throw`, `reject()` will not terminate the control flow. So, if you have code that you want to continue executing after a rejection, you will probably prefer `reject()`.
- Using `throw` in nested promises can cause unexpected results. In such cases, it is recommended to use `reject()`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `Using throw in nested promises can cause unexpected results`? Providing some references on this subject is appreciated.