# Unhandled rejection - Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am new to UnhandledRejection. The below method is supposed to throw  exception and terminate flow but it doesn't.Please favour on resolving it either way

Case 1:
Took value from promise as true and tried conditions.But it is bypassed and returns unhandled rejection with the exception to be thrown.

```
Utils.isMaximumLimitReached(id).then(isLimit=>{
    console.log(isLimit); //true
    if(isLimit){
       throw "not allowed";
    }
  })
```

Edit:
Case 3:This too returns Unhandled rejection this is not allowed

```
const isMaximumLimitReached = coachingId => {
  return db.coachingClassEntries
    .findAndCountAll()
    .then(counts => {
      let numberOfEntries = 2;
      //let maxEntries = counts.rows[0].coachingClass.maxEntries;
      let maxEntries=2;
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if (numberOfEntries == maxEntries) {
           reject('this is not allowed');
      }
      });

    });
};

  Utils.isMaximumLimitReached(data.coachingClassId).then().catch(error=>{
       throw error;
   })
```

Comment: Check This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-an-unhandled-promise-rejection . You need to add the catch block to handle every promise .

Comment: @RohanKadu even with catch block, it throws unhandled rejection

Comment: In the last example you catch and rethrow. I guess what is calling `Utils.isMaximumLimitReached(data.coachingClassId).catch(()=>{...` isn't catching anything.

Comment: @HMR Sorry. I corrected it now. EVen this returns unhandled rejection not allowed.

Comment: Your second code sinippet doesn't seem to return the rejected promise at the `then` stage.

Comment: @Redu second was unorderly. Please consider the present two . edited.

Comment: The last code snippet still doesn't have a `reject` handler, you handle your error in the `resolve` handler. The syntax for `then` is like both answers given is like, with **two** functions as arguments. alternatively, you can change `.then` into `.catch`, which only needs a rejection handler.

Comment: @KevinDrost I tried catch of reject too. It gives the same unhandled rejection

Answer (score 1):

Promise rejections are usually handled with a second callback in the `then` method, which could look like this in your case 1:

```
Utils.isMaximumLimitReached(id).then(()=>{
  // everything is fine
}, (error) => {
  // promise was rejected, handle error
  console.log(error);
})
```

This way, any rejections caused by `isMaximumLimitReached` will be handled in the error callback.

Comment: Case 3 is done as you suggested. I still get Unhandled rejection

Comment: @Gayathri where exactly is the unhandled rejection? If `findAndCountAll` is rejected, you also need to handle that as well.

Comment: INSIDE isMaximumLimitReached , exactly in reject line

Answer (score 1):

Change your Promise.reject with

```
Promise.reject(new Error('409',msg)).then(function() {
  // not called
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error); // Stacktrace
});
```

Hope this helps and resolve your issue. And If you want to throw the error then you [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw) before deciding what to use.

Comment: Could you please check case 3 and let me know what went wrong?