# Javascript (node.js) Promise async/await issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>
{
  try
  {
    await new Promise((resolveSec, rejectSec) =>
    {
      setTimeout(function()
      {
        resolveSec('')
      }, 1000);
    }).then(function(val)
    {
      return reject('should reject') //does not stop execution
      //throw('should reject'); //stops execution
    });
    console.log('not here'); //should not get to here
  }
  catch (err)
  {
    console.log('caught error');
  }
}).catch(function(err)
{
  console.log(err);
});
```

Could someone explain why the above code does not end execution on "reject" but it works with "throw" as I thought that both "reject" and "throw" inside Promise have same functionality.

Comment: Probably has to do with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw

Comment: That's not how Promises are meant to be used. The *entire idea* of Promises is to uncouple sequential asynchronous operations, and here you've got them nested...that's an anti-pattern.

Comment: Calling reject would reject the outer promises, not the one inside the `try` block.

Comment: You meant to `rejectSec` not `reject`.

Comment: Also note that in practice you should almost never use `new Promise`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum especially if you are using async/await which does the Promise wrapping for you.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum why not use `new Promise`? `Promise.resolve` is just a syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause `throw` ends the inner Promises execution, which will then be rethrown by the `await` statement, ending the execution of the outer Promise. `reject` however will set the outer promises state to *rejected*, `return` will end the execution of the inner promisee function but not of the outer one.