# How to ensure an error from an async function is captured without rethrowing the error or using Promise.reject?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Please, look at the following code. Line 5: `return ex`.

When I call `myFunc`, I expect to see `'err'` in the console, but I see `'yes'` which means that outside of `myFunc` the error is not being captured. The error is not bubbling up.

Which makes sense because I'm not rethrowing the error doing: `throw ex` or using `Promise.reject(ex)`.

My Question is: How to ensure the error is captured outside of my function without using the two methods mentioned above? Is there a way?

```
async function myFunc() {
    try {
        throw new Error();
    } catch (ex) {
        return ex;
    }
}

myFunc().then(() => console.log('yes')).catch(() => console.log('err'))
// 'yes'
```

Comment: it's not being "captured" because it's caught, and dealt with by the catch statement - there is no error condition any more

Comment: Like you mentioned, you have to re-throw the error or use Promise.reject - why don't you want to use either of those?

Comment: in this example, don't use try catch and `err` will be logged

Comment: What's the point of using `async` without `await`? If you use `async/await`, `.then()` isn't needed, correct?

Comment: I have to use try catch in my function, this is just an example of how I would call an external service, make sure it works, and if it doesn't, I will return my own Error object. I don't want to rethrow because rethrowing bundles the Error with the stack trace which I do not want.

Comment: There's many circumstances where you would use `async` without `await`, I'm not going to discuss this here because it's not the purpose of this ticket.

Comment: Given the promise chain is working correctly, what is the problem with stack tracing? Is the Error object's "stack" string property of potential use in solving the issue?

Comment: There's no way to be selective about which errors you wanna catch and which don't. If there's a catch, it will catch any kind of error.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `return Proise.reject()` in the catch part? It works as you intend it to work

Comment: Are you just curious whether there is a third way next to `throw` and `Promise.reject`, or do you have an [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) with those?

Comment: I prefer not to mix `async` syntax with `Promise` syntax. It's ugly and makes no sense if you using `async` then just use `async`. If you mix both, then you don't understand how `async` works!

Comment: Bergi, good question. I'm curious. But I guess there's no other way then to re-throw doing `throw ex` on catch

Comment: tracktor53, you make a good point. I've settled on re-throwing the error

Answer (score 1):

When using async functions, you can use the normal javascript `try / catch` to handle errors.

If you throw within an async function, the promise it returned will be rejected.
If you return from an async function (like you did in your `catch` block), the promise will be resolved with the returned value (in your case the exception)

Here two examples how you can handle an async function that might throw:

```js
// async function that might throw
async function funcThatThrows() {
  throw new Error("IT THROWS!");
}

// Exception Handling in other async functions
async function example1() {
  try {
    let result = await funcThatThrows();
    /* ... */
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("example1:", e.message);
  }
}

// Exception handling in non-async functions
function example2() {
  funcThatThrows()
    .then(result => { /* ... */ })
    .catch(err => console.log("example2:", err.message));
}

example1();
example2();
```

See [Javascript Async/Await Error Handling](https://javascript.info/async-await#error-handling) for a detailed tutorial on async error handling :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do this:

```
async function myFunc() {
    try {
        throw new Error();
    } catch (ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to catch and rethrow the exception
```async function myFunc() { throw new Error(); } ```
does exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I had an attempt at answering the question but ended up rewriting my whole answer. At one point, I deleted my answer.

As you already stated in the question, `throw ex` or `Promise.reject(ex)` are the only ways.

When I use `async function` in my application, I usually do so as a means to migrate away from `Promise` chaining and dropping `then` and `catch`. It's really odd that you mix `async function` but call it with `Promise`, `then` and `catch` syntax.

Actually, I think it's dangerous to mix it as indicated here: [JavaScript Promises - reject vs. throw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33446005/881441)

If you indulge me, I want to rewrite your caller using `async function` and `await`:

```js
async function myFunc() {
    throw new Error("Some Error!");
}

( async function () {
  try {
    await myFunc();
    console.log("yes");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err: ", err.message);
  }
} )();
```

This syntax is similar to its synchronous counterpart which infers we ought to use `throw`:

```js
function myFunc() {
    throw new Error("Some Error!");
}

( function () {
  try {
    myFunc();
    console.log("yes");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err: ", err.message);
  }
} )();
```