# await in finally block of async function causes PromiseRejectionHandledWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I'm using `async` `await` in my NodeJs code and the code structure is something as follows.

```js
async function main(){
    try {
        await someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise()
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

async function someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise() {
    try {
        await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                reject('something went wrong')
            }, 1000);
        })
    } catch(e) {
        return Promise.reject(e)
    } finally {
        await cleanup() // remove await here and everything is fine
    }
}


function cleanup() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('cleaup successful')
        }, 1000);
    })
}

main();
```

In the finally block, I'm doing some `async` cleanup that will surely resolve.
But this code is throwing `PromiseRejectionHandledWarning`

```
(node:5710) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: something went wrong
(node:5710) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5710) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
something went wrong
(node:5710) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
```

As far as I understand, I'm not leaving any promise unhandled here.
What am I doing wrong? Should `finally` block by synchronous by design? If yes, why so?

**Update 1:**

If I convert `someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise` to good ol' `then` and `catch`, it works with no problems:

```js
function someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise() {
    return (new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            reject('something went wrong')
        }, 1000);
    })).catch(e => {
        return Promise.reject(e)
    }).finally(() => {
        return cleanup()
    })
}
```

**Update 2:** (Understood the problem)

If I `await` the returning Promise, problem is solved.

```
 return await Promise.reject(e)
```

And this makes me understand what I was doing wrong.
I was breaking the `await` chain (partially synonymous to not returning a `Promise` in `then`/`catch` syntax).
Thanks everyone :)

Comment: The "DeprecationWarning" is thrown because you're not providing a rejection strategy for your `Promise` in `cleanup`. You should never use the `Promise` constructor (unless in some very specific very rare cases). You should add a `try-catch` on `await cleanup()` as well to handle a possible unhandled rejection.

Comment: @briosheje as I mentioned,  "cleanup that will surely resolve"
Think of it as a function that never throws/rejects

Comment: Once again: as long as an `await` is involved, a `Promise` is created. If you don't handle the rejection of that promise, node will give you such warning. This is intended, because the promise might be rejected for any kind of error (whatever generic JAVASCRIPT error, not necessarely promise-related). You must either remove the `await`, either surround the block with a try-catch.

Comment: @briosheje even if I handle `cleanup`, issue still exists

Answer (score 4):

When a Promise rejects, it must be handled *before the current call stack clears*, or there will be an unhandled rejection. You have:

```
} catch (e) {
  return Promise.reject(e)
} finally {
  await cleanup() // remove await here and everything is fine
}
```

If you remove `await`, the `someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise` returns 
*immediately* after the rejected Promise is constructed, so the `Promise.reject(e)`, the rejected Promise, is caught by the `catch` in `main` right after. But if there's any delay, the rejected Promise will *not* be handled immediately; your `await cleanup()` will mean that the rejected Promise goes unhandled for a period of time, before `someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise` returns, which means that `main`'s `catch` can't handle the rejected Promise in time.

Another method you could use would be to wrap the error in an `Error` instead of a `Promise.reject`, and then check if the result is an `instanceof Error` in `main`:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', () => console.log('unhandled rejection!'));

async function main() {
  const result = await someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise();
  if (result instanceof Error) {
    console.log('Error "caught" in main:', result.message);
  }
}

async function someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise() {
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject('something went wrong')
      }, 1000);
    })
  } catch (e) {
    return new Error(e);
  } finally {
    await cleanup()
  }
}


function cleanup() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('cleaup successful')
    });
  })
}

main();
```

Comment: not sure I understand this correctly.
Javascript is working on a single thread.
When you say "Promise goes unhandled for a period of time", what does it mean? The interpreter is still in the function. Function is still being executed. How can Node take control of a Promise that is yet to be returned?

Also, if you see, if I convert `someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise` to `then` and `catch`, it works with no problems.
`try, catch and finally` are just syntax, and they should mean the same, isn't it?

Comment: *The interpreter is still in the function* Not exactly - control flow is inside `someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise` during the time between when the rejected Promise is created and `cleanup`'s `setTimeout` is queued, but then control is yielded back, and other tasks may run in the meantime. Javascript execution does not *completely stop* when an `await` is encountered - it only pauses the *current function* that the `await` is in.

Comment: See  [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyx126t8/) for an example of other JS code running while a Promise is being `await`ed

Comment: thanks for your time :)
I get it partially, but still unsure about why is this happening, will study more on this

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer replace the

`Promise.reject(e)` with `throw e`;

so the function becomes

```
async function someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise() {
   try {
       await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
           setTimeout(() => {
               reject('something went wrong')
           }, 1000);
       })
   } catch(e) {
       throw e;
   } finally {
       await cleanup() // remove await here and everything is fine
   }
}
```

**Reason**

`someFunctionThatReturnsRejectedPromise` method rejects the `Promise` first. So the control flow went to method `main` catch block. 
Later `cleanup` method tries to do the same. Which is to reject the already rejected promise. Thus you get the error

`Promise.reject` is a bit different from `throw` clause. Please refer [throw vs Promise.reject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw)

Which is why removing the `await` from `cleanup()` or removing the `return` from `cleanup` method works. Because that will detach the `Promise` from the current control flow.

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Updated with reason. Please check