# Is there a difference between Promise.reject and throw in this example

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, coffeescript

I have seen something in our codebase while refactoring coffeescript->js and I am a bit anxious if I break something if I change it, I haven't seen `return Promise.reject(new Error('not found'));` before

```js
// This is old code
somePromise()
  .then(function (res) {
    if ((res == null)) { return Promise.reject(new Error('not found')); }
    return 'found'
  })
```

```js
somePromise()
  .then(function (res) {
    if ((res == null)) { throw new Error('not found'); }
    return 'found'
  })
```

Comment: Hello, does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw

Comment: FWIW, the answers to the linked question didn't cover one very minor aspect of this, so [I've done that now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw/63373036#63373036).