# why throw inside of an setTimeout, located inside a promise, doesn't change state and result of the output promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, throw

I know existence of a `throw` inside of a `promise`, change the state of that specific promise to `rejected` and the result will be the `error` message, but when I type this `throw` inside of a `setTimeout` located inside of a `promise`, that `throw` doesn't modify the state and result of that `promise`, at first I thought maybe there is something wrong with `setTimeout`, but I tried `resolve()` and `reject()` inside that `setTimeout` and I received the expected result. so I wonder why this happen with a `throw` located in `setTimeout` inside of a `promise`?

code:

```
const test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error("error");
}, 2000)
});

//output after 2 sec: [[PromiseState]]: pending
                    //[[PromiseResult]]: undefined;
```

```
 const test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("success");
 }, 2000)
 });

 //output after 2 sec:[[PromiseState]]: fulfilled
                    //[[PromiseResult]]: success
```

Comment: Do the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw is helpful ?

Comment: "*a `throw` inside of a promise changes the state of that specific promise to rejected and the result will be the error*" - yes, any **synchronous exception** in the executor function will reject the promise, whether from a  `throw` statement of something else. But not any `throw` just because it's located syntactically inside the function.

Comment: the accepted answer has mentioned my issue but why this is even happening from the first place?@RomanLytvynov

Comment: @lome1446 Simply because there's nothing special about promises. If you `throw` inside a `setTimeout` callback, it's an uncaught exception in your application.

Answer (score 0):

The Error is thrown in the context of the `setTimeout` callback function and it only exists in that context.

The Promise does not know what happens inside that callback, until/unless you make it call `resolve` or `reject`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your setTimeout callback to:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    reject(new Error("error"))
}, 2000)
```

Comment: tnx for the answer, but I wasn't looking for a solution, I was looking why this event is occurring.